# How to use asprintf

Tags: c

i want to create somethink like this:

```
void funkcja(char *charTmp2){
    asprintf(&charTmp2, "%i %.2f %s", 2, 3.20, "PIERWSZY");
}

int main() {
    char *tmp;
    funkcja(tmp);
    printf("%s\n", tmp);
}
```

I dont know why, there is no output. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `funkcja()` is only altering it's local copy of the pointer, try this

```
ssize_t funkcja(char **charTmp2)
 {
    return asprintf(charTmp2, "%i %.2f %s", 2, 3.20, "PIERWSZY");
 }

int main() 
 {
    char *tmp;
    if (funkcja(&tmp) != -1)
     {
        printf("%s\n", tmp);
        free(tmp)
     }
 }
```